# fill textbox with values based on selected table cell value (ajax call & mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table which is populated by values obtained from mysql database. I want to use an ajax call function so that when I click a cell -  based on the cell value the textboxes get filled. Now the data in the textboxes will be from another table in the mysql database.

So an example of how it would work is:

I have one table for credentials, which shows user name and their user id.

On the website this is shown as a table. Now when i click the a cell which has a user name. The textbox would be populated by the users say total exams taken which is obtained from exams table in the mysql.

I am totally stumped on how to go about doing this. Please can someone help!

Comment: Get the id from the selected cell, post it using ajax, get the results from the server and update your html content.

Comment: Go through tons of tutorials out there about AJAX/PHP/MySQL integration, try something first and then come back when you're stuck

Comment: thanks il give that a try again ive been spend half the day looking at tutorials. But thats the way to do it I guess slowly slowly it will begin making sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using ajax .

use this

```
$("#cell").click(function(){
$.get("file.php?id="+$(this).val(),function(data){
$("#textboxid").val(data);
})
})
```

the `file.php` is the file which will perform the back-hand calling to database and make a output.

Comment: some further comment on how this fixes issue might help this new user